# Trouble with drawing strings

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm trying to make a nice gui for downloading some stuff and I'm trying to add some text explaining how to use the gui. The only problem is the text isn't appearing. Here is all relevant code.

```
public static class Dissplay extends JPanel{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString("Please enter you plugin folder location and what you want to install.", 30, 20);
    }
}
static JTextField input;
static JCheckBox villagesBox;
static JCheckBox slabsBox;
static JFrame window;
static boolean clicked;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    clicked = false;
    input = new JTextField("Enter plugin folder location here");
    input.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            if(clicked){

            } else {
                input.setText("");
                clicked = true;
            }
        }
    });
    JPanel content1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel content2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel content3 = new JPanel();
    content3.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    content1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    content2.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));
    content3.add(input, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    content3.add(new Dissplay(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    villagesBox = new JCheckBox("Villages");
    content1.add(content3, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    villagesBox.setSelected(false);
    slabsBox = new JCheckBox("Slabs");
    slabsBox.setSelected(false);
    content2.add(villagesBox);
    content2.add(slabsBox);
    JButton button = new JButton("Go");
    ActionListener buttonLisener = new Button();
    button.addActionListener(buttonLisener);
    content1.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    window = new JFrame();
    window.setContentPane(content1);
    window.add(content2, 0);
    window.setSize(200, 150);
    window.setLocation(100, 100);
    window.setVisible(true);

}
```

No clue what's wrong.

Comment: no clue what this means " ActionListener buttonLisener = new Button();" is this some kind of new programming??

Comment: Doesn't compile for me. This line... `ActionListener buttonLisener = new Button();`. Button doesn't implement ActionListener, so this is invalid.

Comment: That is for the button. It's contained in a different class.

Comment: Also, public static class is wrong. And several variable declarations and your main method are sitting outside of the class.

Comment: You didn't create a custom class simply called Button, did you?

Comment: After correcting your compilation issues, I get a simple UI displaying with a textbox stating "Enter plugin folder location here", two checkboxes (Villages & Slabs) and a Go Button. I used the standard java.awt.Button. Not sure what your Button is. It could be part of your problem.

Comment: Everything but text works. That's my problem.

Comment: @ManoDestra yes i have a class called button but my problem currently is i can't get just plain old text to display aka my painConponent isn't working.

Comment: Why not just use a JLabel instead? And I'd recommend renaming your custom class to be more meaningful than just "Button". Too easily confused with the java.awt.Button class.

Comment: You may have to call the repaint() on the JPanel that you've created, if it's contained within a JFrame object. Look into that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830603/drawing-text-within-a-jpanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to your woes. You need to call the setPreferredSize method on your JPanel object. It quite bizarrely defaults to a 10x10 Dimension initially. Once you up that, you'll be able to see your drawn text.

```
public static class Dissplay extends JPanel{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Dissplay() {
        super();
        this.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(600, 100));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString("Please enter you plugin folder location and what you want to install.", 30, 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. also I did change my button class name like you suggested in the comment on my post. :)

Comment: You're very welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try to set font, color, etc. Something like this :

```
g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, fontSize));

g.setColor(Color.red);

g.drawString("some string", 40, 40);
```

Comment: no didn't work. nice try